# Convert an Object's Name to a String

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
var variable:Object=new Object();
```

How would you convert "variable" as an object to "variable" as a string? I thought this would work:

```
var variable:Object=new Object();
var variable_string=String(variable);
```

Comment: `var variable_string = "variable"`. Since there’s no way to refer to a variable or a property without knowing its name in some form, you can always either use a string literal or the expression you’d use to get the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the name of a variable that holds an instance via said instance.

You could store the instance in an `Object` against a given key, which could be found using a `for...in` loop:

```
var myObject:Object = {};
var objects:Object = { variable: myObject };

for(var i:String in objects)
{
    if(objects[i] === myObject)
    {
        trace(i); // variable
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All class level member names are stored in the string constant pool in your compiled SWF. Thus, it is in fact technically possible to get the name of variable by loading the bytes of the SWF and parsing them (or by using someone else's API to do it). However, this is probably more trouble than it's worth for whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: My way around this problem was to set a string property for the variable. var variable:Object=new Object(); variable.string="variable";